# Ajax post в Spring MVC выдает ошибку 404

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Написал функцию отправки данных на сервак с помощью `jQuery-ajax`. Вроде все правильно, но выдает ошибку 404.

#### js-файл:

```js
function json(itemId, quantity, type) {
    let item = {};
    item["id"] = itemId;
    item["path"] = window.location.pathname;
    item["quantity"] = quantity;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test/ajax",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (e) {
            console.log("success!!!")
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Error!!!")
        },
        done: function (e) {
            console.log("Done!!!")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вскорее всего ошибка связана с тем, что у вас не отключен `csrf`.

Чтобы отключить `csrf` -

Если вы не хотите отключать данную вещь, вам придется сделать несколько действий:

1. Добавьте в файл `Thymeleaf` (`JSP` я не пользуюсь) следующие строки:

```html
<meta th:name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta th:name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

2. В `js-файл` добавим:

```js
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

//код $.ajax

beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
},
```

в итоге наш js-файл должен выглядеть так:

```js
function json(itemId, quantity, type) {
    let item = {};
    item["id"] = itemId;
    item["path"] = window.location.pathname;
    item["quantity"] = quantity;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        url: "/test/ajax",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (e) {
            console.log("success!!!")
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Error!!!")
        },
        done: function (e) {
            console.log("Done!!!")
        }
    })
}
```